# Apply user agent stylesheet to a div?

Tags: html, css

I have been researching how I could apply a user agent stylesheet to a div.

Is this possible?

Specifically, I want to apply the user agent stylesheet of input to a div within one of my web applications.

Comment: So you want to turn off the other stylesheets and give the element the system look and feel?

Comment: Well, more or less I want a div to have the same style as inherited user agent stylesheet, essetnially giving the look and feel of a specific input while it not being an input but a div.

Comment: Nah, that's hard, you could go with `initial` values for that cointaner but it would not probably affect the input. Or your could add `:not(.the-div-you-want-to-keep-native)` to your CSS selectors

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there is a way to make one element inherit the styles of another easily. You could try to loop over an input's computedStyle and apply it to a div, but that may do more than you want (i.e. it will probably pick up its size and shape as well). It also isn't particularly elegant:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle

One thing you might do is to put an input absolutely positions inside the div, and set it to the div's full height and width, so it stretches over it. Then disable it but set the background color to white. Or, put another div over the top of it to prevent clicks on it and take it out of the tab order:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p040gdos/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <input id="backgroundInput" tabindex="-1" />
    <div id="cover">content goes here</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

#backgroundInput {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

#cover {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```